# Typsetting my answer is hard unless I first post it

Tags: support, typesetting

I have noticed a change in the stackexchange mathjax typsetting viewer over the past few months:

The "preview" that is displayed when I real-time type my answer is not as attentive as it used to be: Sometimes I have to "post" my answer for it to be displayed with correct typesetting (so then I can make corrections as needed).   This is   annoying and it results in my (necessarily) posting a set of **drafts** of my answer, **only for me to see the draft displayed correctly so that I can appropriately make changes**.  An obvious "fix" is to just wait for the system to correctly display my work in the preview mode...yet, lately, the preview seems to stall until I post.

**Q: Is this just me and my computer, or is anyone else noticing this? Can anything be done?**

I imagine that such posts-only-to-edit are confusing to readers who do not know these are only drafts. My current solution is just to make my fixes as quickly as possible to minimize the time my rough-drafts are displayed as answers.

[This is of course distinct from other situations where I post an answer that I think is good, only to notice typos/mistakes that I edit later. That situation is due to my own human-error, not the fault of the system.]

Comment: I do not see how the given link answers my question.  Is this recent change I have noticed common to others?  How does that sandbox link help?

Comment: it gives you a place other than the question you are work8ngnon to post to...

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee : Posting to that place is one particular approach to address the issue I raise: It is not the only approach and is not necessarily the most convenient. Other strategies may include allowing a preview button that just re-renders in my current preview display when I push it. I also do not know if something in stackexchange has changed in the past few months, or not.  Objectively, I do not see how one particular approach can be viewed as "the answer" to my question, and I do not see why any further discussion should be stymied.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I don't think this is a duplicate: Michael is asking about *why* the preview issue occurs, whereas the linked question provides a space to *deal* with such things.

Comment: My bad. @Noah, it didn't answer the why, but it did explain how to solve the problem in a different way... So kinda duplicate! :)

Comment: Here's another compile a pdf of it using actual pdfTeX or LaTeX

Comment: or https://www.overleaf.com/ instead of verbosus.com (VerbTeX compiler)

Comment: Also the preview is no longer perfectly in sync - which is a big pain if you want tight control over typesetting. I complained about this a few times here in the past over the years, and they fixed it once, so maybe there is some hope they will fix it again.

Comment: @Bill, at least you have preview, mobile doesn't get anything but add a picture, without clicking the full site link. Same with flagging. Review is semi difficult unless you know partsof the URL format, etc.